# How do I read Row Wise instead of column wise with h5py?

Tags: python, matlab, dataset, reshape, h5py

I have this matlab file that is of shape 70x10,000,000 (10,000,000 columns 70 rows)
Whats annoying is that when I run this line of code which is supposed to print that chunk of data,

```
f = h5py.File(filepath, 'r')
item = list(f.items())[0][1]
print(item)
```

it reshapes it into 10,000,000x70 (10,000,000 rows, 70 columns)
Is there a way to keep the original shape ?

Comment: MATLAB is Fortran style, column major.  HDF5 and h5py/numpy is C, row major.  Apparently MATLAB does the transpose when writing the matrix to the file.  So in both places, the inner most dimension 70.

Comment: I understand that but how do I fix it so that it is column major?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h5py returns HDF5 data as Numpy arrays. So, the key to using h5py is using Numpy methods when needed. You can easily transpose an array using `np.transpose()`. A simple example is provided below. It creates a HDF5 file with 2 datasets: 1) an array with shape (20,5), and 2) the transposed array with shape (5,20). Then it extracts the 2 arrays and uses `np.transpose()` to switch row/column order.

```
with h5py.File('SO_67031436','w') as h5w:
    arr = np.arange(100.).reshape(20,5)
    h5w.create_dataset('ds_1',data=arr)
    h5w.create_dataset('ds_1t',data=np.transpose(arr))
    
with h5py.File('SO_67031436','r') as h5r:
    for name in h5r:
        print(name,',shape=',h5r[name].shape)
        arr=np.transpose(h5r[name][:])
        print('transposed shape=',arr.shape)
```